# How does one write the possessive of "Elizabeth II" or similar usages?

Tags: grammaticality, possessives

Monarchs are often identified by Roman numerals, as in "Henry VIII" or "Elizabeth II".

How does one write the possessive for this usage? "Elizabeth II's" looks right but feels somehow wrong, as if it expands as "Elizabeth Two's".

Comment: "Elizabeth II's" would be pronounced as "Elizabeth the Second's", not as "Elizabeth Two's".

Comment: The Roman numeral after a monarch's name is considered to be [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regnal_number), not cardinal, as herisson says. In fact it is called the monarch's 'ordinal'. Elizabeth II's reign, Henry VIII's wives, George III's madness.

Comment: "The possessions of Elizabeth II"